# Let's get in sync about what we mean by [synchronization]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[synchronization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization) can have two meanings:

- An issue with [thread-safety](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thread-safety) / [locking](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locking) / [concurrency](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concurrency)
- Copying and reconciling versions of data which may have diverged

The two senses of the word are barely related to each other, and probably shouldn't bear the same tag.

What should we do with the tag?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that a majority of the questions correspond with the former, so perhaps we can keep the tag for just those questions.  If need be, we can rename this original tag (maybe [thread-synchronization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thread-synchronization) would work for the former) and create a new tag for the latter questions.  It would allow us to keep this tag while avoiding misuse.

---

**Update:** I instead made the changes as suggested in the comments:

1. Tagged questions unrelated to process synchronization with a new [sync](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sync) tag
2. Synonymized [synchronization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization) with [thread-safety](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thread-safety), with the latter as the master (this can always be changed)

Comment: I'd go with the rename even if we are only going to have one synchronization tag, just to make clear what this one means.

Comment: @Pimgd: I also couldn't find very many non-threading questions within that tag, so it may not be needed for them.  A few tag removals and a tag merge would be an easy fix.

Comment: Let's retag the few copying-and-reconciliation questions with a new [tag:sync] tag, then synonymize [synchronization] with [tag:thread-safety]?

Comment: That's fine with me.